# No puedo visualizar mi app con Yii Framework

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, yii

hice una app con PHP, MySQL 3.2 y Yii Framework 1.

Monte todo el proyecto en GitHub, lo descargué, volví a instalar Yii, Composer, pero no logro visualizar mi app. Sólo me muestra el índice de directorio.
Accedo a la ruta `http://localhost/yii/servisoft-master/`y obtengo `Index of /yii/servisoft-master`.

Agrdesco su pronta ayuda

Comment: En el listado de `Index of ...`, ¿no aparece ningún archivo llamado `index.php`?

Comment: Solo sale el encarpetado de vistas, modelo, controller.

Comment: ¿Y es lo mismo que tienes actualmente en GitHub?, ¿o en el listado de archivos del repositorio tienes todos los archivos y carpetas del proyecto?

Comment: no es el mismo es diferente decidi hacerlo nuevamente

Comment: Si es diferente, te sugiero volver a descargarlo como ZIP o clonarlo con el comando `git clone https://github.com/username/project`, habiendo instalado previamente Git en tu PC.